MUI Table overflows height of parent flexbox
I have a Box component inside a flex container that is designed to fit the width and height of the screen. When the Box is empty, it behaves as expected, perfectly fitting the screen dimensions. However, when I add a Table component to the Box, which is very large in both height and width, it causes the Box to overflow its height. This makes the Box unusable because I need to scroll all the way to the bottom to reach the horizontal scrollbar.
Here’s the code I’m using:
<Box sx={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'orange' }}>
    <Table stickyHeader>
        <TableHead>...</TableHead>
        <TableBody>...</TableBody>
    </Table>
</Box>

Issue Description:
When the Box is empty, it correctly fits the width and height of the screen.
When a large Table is added, the height of the Box expands beyond the viewport, making it difficult to access the horizontal scrollbar.
Without the Table

With the Table

What I’ve Tried:
I’ve tried adjusting the flex properties and various height settings, but the Box still overflows when the content is large.
How Can I Ensure the Box Remains Within the Screen Dimensions and Provides Scrollbars for Overflowing Content?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Add your CSS without its hard, have you tried set a max width/height?

There is not css other than this

Oh, have you tried setting a max width/height, overlflow: auto?
